# Multiple filter in sonata admin

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-2.8

I want to have that a filtered field in sonata admin datagrid mapper can be OR or AND connected with the user given filter values ... for example the field "Name" can be "John" or "Sandy" ...
In the docs on https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html they write

```
 ->add('tags', null, array(), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
```

where i aspect, that the keword "multiple" should allow a field to be added multiple times ... but all i get is, that "multiple" and "expanded" is not a valid option for this field.

How can i let the user filter by AND or OR conditions?

Thanks

Comment: `expanded` and `multiple` are options for drop-down lists, 1st makes it always open, 2nd lets you select multiple values - not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Sonata 4.x, an exemple of working code

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter): void
{
    /* ... */
    $filter
        ->add('tags', null, [
            'field_options' => [
                'multiple'  =>  true,
            ]
        ]);
}
```